# Details of multipass instance

Tags: virtualization, multipass

"The multipass launch command without any argument will create and start a new instance"

Not clear to me what is actually happening with this.  Is it running Ubuntu on another computer, x11/ssh/rlogin/etc ?  Or does it create a local virtual machine?

Is the instance persistent, or does it (and all its data & history) cease to exist when you're done with it?

If remote and persistent, does it make you the only user, or might there be other login accounts on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Local

It creates a local virtual machine. [The first sentence of the documentation says as much.](https://multipass.run/docs)

## Persistent

Once created the instance of Multipass is persistent.

See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1359346/is-there-a-published-implementation-of-qubesos-convert-to-trusted-pdf-on-ubunt/1359515#1359515) for an example of **non-persistant** use of Multipass.

## Sole User

There are no other login accounts on it. The only user is called `ubuntu`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yes, it helps—thanks!.  The frequent use of the word "cloud" is what makes it sound like some remote thing.  I'm accustomed to the term "Virtual machine."  Microsoft used to have a thing where I could use an iPad as a keyboard/mouse/display for a Windows running on one of their servers.  I wasn't interested in something of that sort.

Comment: @WGroleau the idea is you can try things out locally as if you are working on the cloud. When everything works you can do it on the cloud, assuming that is the ultimate goal.